# Android TypeNotFoundException on HTC Desire Z

Tags: android

I am using the following code for parsing JSON -

```
            /**
             * ScoreReader.java
             */

            package ca.cbc.mobile.android.model;

            import java.io.BufferedReader;
            import java.io.File;
            import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
            import java.io.FileOutputStream;
            import java.io.FileReader;
            import java.io.IOException;
            import java.io.InputStream;
            import java.io.InputStreamReader;
            import java.io.Reader;
            import java.lang.reflect.Type;
            import java.net.URL;
            import java.net.URLConnection;
            import java.util.List;

            import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
            import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
            import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
            import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
            import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
            import ca.cbc.mobile.android.model.HNICBoxScore;

            import android.os.Environment;
            import android.util.Log;

            import com.google.gson.Gson;
            import com.google.gjson.reflect.TypeToken;

            public class BoxScoreReader
            {

                // static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HNICBoxScoreReader.class);
                private static final String TAG = "HNICCompletedBoxScoreReader";



                List<HNICBoxScore> boxScoreList = null;


                public List<HNICBoxScore> readBoxScores(String jsonFile)
                {
                    String json = null;


                    try
                    {
                        URL url = new URL(jsonFile);
                        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                connection.getInputStream()));
                        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                        String inputLine;

                        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                            buffer.append(inputLine);
                        json = buffer.toString();

                        Gson gson = new Gson();

                        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<HNICBoxScore>>()
                        {
                        }.getType();
                        boxScoreList = gson.fromJson(json, listType);



                        if (boxScoreList != null)
                        {
                            for (HNICBoxScore boxScore : boxScoreList)
                            {
                                // logger.debug(boxScore);
                                Log.d(TAG, "----------------------" + boxScore.getAway());
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Log.d(TAG, "--------------------------------problems reading completed box score");
                        }


                    } catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        // logger.error(e);

                        Log.e(TAG, "---------------------problems reading completed box score" + e.toString());
                    }
                    return boxScoreList;
                }
            }
```

But I'm getting the following exception -

TypeNotFoundException

I am using the gson library for parsing json.

OS : Android 2.2

Hardware : HTC Desire Z

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this problem reported here -

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1760

and I found the solution to this problem here -

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=255

Basically, I followed these steps -

If anyone else has this problem, here's a quick how-to fix it:

1. Download jarjar (http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/downloads/list)
2. Put jarjar-1.0.jar and gson-1.5.jar in the same folder
3. Create a new text file in this folder (rules.txt)
4. Write the following line in the textfile: rule com.google.gson.** com.google.myjson.@1
5. From the commandline, open jarjar with the command "java -jar jarjar.jar process rules.txt gson-1.5.jar myjson-1.5.jar"
6. Replace the gson library in your project with myjson and update the imports

and that solved the issue for me.